# HTTP get not calling data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have three Get requests for an API, so I reused the function just by passing the URL, which differentiates one from the other. However when I see the step by step the provider returns the data, but the page response function does not receive them, getting as null or more specific, "Unexpected end of JSON".

Page Code:

```
carregaNatureza() {
    this.despesaProvider.getComboBoxes('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/v1/cadastros/natureza/get-dropdownlist/002/001')
    .then((arr_proj) => {

        this.obj_data = arr_proj;

        this.lista_natureza = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.lista_natureza.length; i++) {
            this.obj += (
                this.lista_natureza[i]
            )
            this.lista_natureza.push(this.obj);
        }
    })
}
```

Provider code:

```
getComboBoxes(url: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + this.global.tokenGlobal);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(url, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
          var json_data = (response as any)._body;
          var parsed = JSON.parse(json_data);

          var arr_data = [];

          for (var x in parsed) {
              arr_data.push(parsed[x]);
          }

          return arr_data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          var json_error = (error as any)._body;
          var parsed = JSON.parse(json_error);

          var arr = [];

          for (var x in parsed) {
              arr.push(parsed[x]);
          }

          return arr[0];
      });
  }
```

Comment: whats the response type? Unexpected end of JSON meaning server is sending text/string response and you are accessing it as json

Comment: The answer type is JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your stuck due to this line of code. try console.log(arr_proj) first.

```
  this.obj_data = arr_proj; //u initialize response here
  this.lista_natureza = []; //empty array
  for (let i = 0; i < this.lista_natureza.length; i++) {//checking length of empty array it wont let you come inside because you fail for condition
    this.obj += (
        this.lista_natureza[i]
        ) //rewriteing your actual response 
    this.lista_natureza.push(this.obj);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain this answer? This piece of code is identical to the question code.

Comment: I have commented the statement in answer. he is trying to rewriting his actual response. that's why I pointed his mistake with comment.